# setting scrollHeight for p-dropdown throws an error

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, primeng

I'm trying to set the scrollHeight value to '300px' in p-dropdown, When I serve the application no error is thrown but the scrollbar shows up at 200px only. Also unit test case for the same fails with 'setting getter only value scrollHeight'. I need to set the scroll height as my list will be populated dynamically.
Any answer would be appreciated.
Thanks.
versions used
angular - 4.1.2,
primeng - 4.0.1

```
    `<p-dropdown 
                [options]="options"
                [scrollHeight]="scrollHeight"
     </p-dropdown>`
```

in component i have

`scrollHeight: string = '300px'`

Comment: The root cause for this issue was the version of ngPrime doesn't support the scrollHeight setting. updating it fixed the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tested this in plnkr, and it works fine.  I would suggest trying it in plnkr as well to see if you can duplicate the problem.  I have successfully used:

```
scrollHeight: string = '300px';
```

Use this as your base:  [New Issue Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qi2Nw2imLpDUF8NJinYw?p=preview)

Comment: Hi BillF, I've tried this in plnkr and it works fine. But when i use the same in my app, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Development tools are your friend.  Inspect your dropdown and play with the style settings related to height.  If changing some of those settings fix the height, look at the which setting is overriding the 300px.  Otherwise, it may be that you are using older version of primeng and need to update.